# Print Line of Specified Length in R

Tags: r

This seems really simple but I haven't been able to find a solution. I want to be able to print a horizontal line of a specified length.

What I've tried so far is:

```
cat(rep("-",10))
- - - - - - - - - -
```

However, I don't want the spaces between the dashes, what I want to see is:

```
----------
```

I also tried pasting together but this also doesn't give me the result I'm looking for.

```
paste0(rep("-",10))
[1] "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-"
```

No doubt this has a very simple solution, thanks in advance.

Comment: `cat(paste(rep("-",10), collapse= ""))` ?

Comment: Exactly what I needed, I knew the answer was simple enough. Appreciate the help.